# Where is the "go!" button on the render tab in 2.8?

Tags: rendering

So I have a scene in the layout tab, I've gone to the render tab, I've chosen "new image", and I can set dimensions like 1920x1080. But all it does is change the size of a large black box. Where is the button that says "go!" or "render!" that makes it actually render something in the black box that I can then save?

Is a rendering supposed to show in the black box automatically and it just isn't working? Or if there's a button that starts the render where is it?

I'm just trying to make one frame render at this point.

Here's a picture of what I see:

[image]

Comment: On the top left there is a button 'Render'

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I see, I'm not seeing a render button anywhere.

Comment: Actually, I can render from the menu render->render image (f12), but that doesn't seem to be attached to the render tab in any way and opens a completely new window.

Comment: Top left of your screen shot is a button called 'Render' click on it and choose Render Image. Blender 2.8 is different from 2.79b, the render options, output formats and actual button to render are separated

Comment: You're talking about the render menu. That works, but I'm trying to figure out how to use the render tab, where there's a big black box that looks like an image should render inside of it. Are you saying that box isn't supposed to do anything, and that rendering isn't actually done on the render tab? The render menu is available on all tabs.

Comment: Im not sure why we can create new images, but if you want to show your render result, you can just select just that in the drop down menu. At the moment, in your screenshot, your selected Image is named 'test' where 'Renderresult' should be. And to have a renderresult, you have to have rendered something first, else it will be a grey image with a grey grid on it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First (1) Setup your size and output
Second (2) check your layers ready to be rendered.

Then go to the *Render* menu and select *Render* (<kbd>F12</kbd>). This is the default "GO" button on Blender 2.8. I know you´re asking for the big buttons on 2.79, they´re gone.

[image]

A lot of users on the Blender community are asking for those buttons to be back, you're not the only one. This was a recent change.

Comment: What is the purpose of the render tab then, if you can set the settings in the layout tab (on the scene object), and then render using the render menu that is available on all tabs? Is the render tab just a way to view previous renders?

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives start to appear

https://blenderartists.org/t/big-render-button-for-blender-2-80/1159414

[image]

or https://github.com/Mitsuma/Blender2.8-RenderButton

[image]